# Firefox background-image disappear after switching tabs

Tags: css, firefox, background-image

I have some very weird issue with firefox while rendering background-images. I'm not sure if it's a firefox bug or simply my fault.

Every time I open my project site in firefox all background images are loaded and displayed correctly. After I switch to another tab and switch back after a while all background images disappeared. I checked the network analysis tab in the developer tools and all files are loaded correctly. Also in some situations parts of the images appear after I select some text over it. After parts of a second all the images show up. So I assume it's a rendering bug in firefox.

My images are implemented like:

```
background-image:url("path/to/image.png");
background-size:cover;
background-position:center center;
```

Is there a workaround for that bug? Is that even a bug? Can anyone confirm that? I searched the web and I couldn't find anything...

[image: weird background-image bug? (image. not enough rep yet...)]

Comment: So it works fine in Chrome and IE? Also, you're showing your IP on the image. Can be problematic if its static.

Comment: I think that is rather the browser trying to save resources … For tabs that are not currently visible, they might get partially “unloaded” to save on CPU and/or RAM.

Comment: @CBroe that might be the case, I thought of that, too. But it's weird that sometime I have to wait a few seconds. That's too long for users!

Comment: @Gezzasa The IP is no problem since it's the default ip range when you share your internet connection on windows. Chrome and IE not tested, but Edge is fine.

Comment: @Gezzasa that's an internal IP address, so I guess it doesn't matter as much?

Comment: Couldn't reproduce that behavior in IE, Edge or Chrome.

Comment: I'm having the same issue in March 2020. It's affecting both the dev and prod versions of a site I'm working on. It only seems to happen in Firefox. Sometimes the background image comes back in pieces, which looks super-weird. Sometimes it doesn't come back at all, unless I refresh the page.

Comment: Same problem in April 2020. Firefox 75

Comment: @DanRobinson See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this bug after a long day of experimenting with CSS background images and radial gradients for a site of mine before I eventually realised this was a bug in Firefox and not my CSS. The bug is now confirmed to have [been fixed](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1625571) in Firefox 76, which is scheduled for release to the Stable channel on May 6. To get hold of Firefox 76 before May 6, [go here](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/76.0beta/releasenotes/) to download the 76 Beta and switch to the Beta channel. Just don't forget to switch back to the Stable channel when Firefox 76 is eventually released on May 6.

Comment: As best as I can tell, Mozilla has indeed fixed this issue. (I'm currently running Firefox 81.0, and I don't see the problem recurring.) Thanks for the information, @Prometheus!