# Firefox background images vanish in idle out-of-focus browser tabs

Tags: html, css

Three years later, I am experiencing the same exact issue as an unresolved post ([Firefox background-image disappear after switching tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42366232/firefox-background-image-disappear-after-switching-tabs)).

The background images set in CSS are vanishing after some idle time in out-of-focus browser tabs. Returning to the tab sometimes shows the background image, and sometimes not. A page refresh always shows it (though there is an annoying 2 sec delay between page content load and background image load).

This is particularly annoying when using white text on top of a dark background image, as I am doing for a title statement on a home page, or worse I imagine if somebody places text in an actual background image (though I don't recommend the latter).

This issue appears to be specific to Firefox and still reproduces with all Firefox Add-ons disabled.

Firefox version:  74.0 (64-bit)

CSS:

```
body {
    /* font and other unrelated bits redacted for less clutter */
    background: url("../images/my_background.png") no-repeat top center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: contain;
    -moz-background-size: contain;
    -o-background-size: contain;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center 108px;
}
```

Anyone else experiencing this and have a work-a-round?  Design-wise, I'd like to retain the white body text on a dark background image if possible.

Cheers!

Comment: Add a fallback background color ? or colors also vanish ?

Comment: Maybe report it at the [Mozilla Bugtracker](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/)?

Comment: Thanks Zohir. I didn't test yet if colors retain yet. That may be a backup plan if colors retain but it would impact the visual appearance I'm seeking so was hoping for a work-a-round that preserves appearance.

Comment: Thanks Coli. I opened bug https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1625571.  The team at BugZilla jumped on this very quickly and are working to fix. (Shameless plug for BubZilla team for their quick and professional response!)

Comment: And of course thanks to Zohir and Coli for equally quick replies here ;)